# magento 2 unable to redirect to external url from observer

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, log

I made modules that work fine but unable to redirect to another url when event fired

what code does when adding to cart is pressed I want to redirect to other URL say google.com

my module works as a log file is generated.

I also get error when i inspected console:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Devshree\Affliliate\Observer\GetQuote::_redirect() in **/var/www/html/magento/app/code/Devshree/Affliliate/Observer/GetQuote.php** on line **15**

below is my code :

**Devshree\Affliliate\etc\frontend\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_save_before">
        <observer name="devshree_affliliate_event_obs" instance="Devshree\Affliliate\Observer\GetQuote" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Devshree\Affliliate\Observer\GetQuote.php**

```
namespace Devshree\Affliliate\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class GetQuote implements ObserverInterface {
        public function execute(Observer $observer) {
            $myfile = fopen("/var/www/html/magento/var/logdebug.log", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $abc = "heello";
            fwrite($myfile, print_r($abc,true));
            fclose($myfile);
            return $this->_redirect('*/auth/login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe the redirect method is inherited when you're in a controller class, not an observer. You'd need to access the response object then call redirect on that

Comment: Perhaps a plugin might be more suitable than an observer here?

Comment: @RobbieAverill can you please edit my code to tell what should  i do , i made it modules do you have some plugin so i can check

Comment: Google it, try something then ask here if you can't get it to work. I have a question on here about observers vs plugins, look it up. They're similar only a plugin would let you hook into any public function not just Magento events

Comment: ok can you will that way i tried using observer is worng can it be done via observer in someway

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to external URL from observer like below :

```
namespace Devshree\Affliliate\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;

class GetQuote implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_response;

    public function __construct(
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        ResponseInterface $response 
    ){
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $myfile = fopen("/var/www/html/magento/var/logdebug.log", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $abc = "heello";
        fwrite($myfile, print_r($abc,true));
        fclose($myfile);
        $this->_redirect->redirect($this->_response, '*/auth/login');
    }
}
```

Comment: hey __construct seems broken can you check

Comment: seems not working.........

Comment: check the edited ans

Comment: hey worked but issue it that add to cart is done via ajax when i inspect console i see it was calling auth/login , but did not redirected to that url

Comment: bro can you help how to fix it

Comment: what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: i want to redirect user to other url when add to cart is pressed now after adding moduleswhen i inspected developer console i see auth/login was called but my webpage was not redirected to auth/login.

i think i may be due to ajax add to cart think sample linke: http://45.55.147.158/jockey-1.html

Comment: bro please help me to fix it i can donate some amout for help, i have stuck for 2 days

Comment: try this `$this->_redirect->redirect($this->_response, 'customer/account/login');`

Comment: hey module code it okay it due to ajax add to cart that why this module does not work did you check url i gave click add to cart inspect element in network tab you will know what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38523/discussion-between-manashvi-birla-and-mcoder).