# Magento 2 : Event Observer Exception Not Showing in Screen

Tags: magento2, event-observer, exception

In custom extension, I create observer like this.

```
app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_remove_item">
    <observer name="sales_quote_remove_item_handler" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\RemovecartbeforeObserver" shared="false" />
  </event>
</config>
```

And My Observer:

```
app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\RemovecartbeforeObserver.php

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RemovecartbeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
       // HERE IS MY CODE
       $message = "THIS IS CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE";
       throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($message));
       return;
    }
 }
```

My Observer function is called, but it not show custom error on the page. Instade of this it show my message in `exception.log` file like this.

```
main.CRITICAL: exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'THIS IS CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE' in E:\xampp\htdocs\myworks\magento213\app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\RemovecartbeforeObserver.php:106
```

See how it show default message.
[image]

Comment: How did your page look like when the observer was executed?

Comment: It show default message "We can't remove the item." instade of custom message. I update question check now.

Comment: Are you sure the think you want to execute is executed? How to debug: try sending output to browser like `Hello Nasty World!` and add `exit` to exit the code execution above the `$message = 'blablabla'` line. If you see the message, then you can go to the next step. Try it and let me now if the `Hello Nasty World!` is sent to the browser.

Comment: Yes, If I put exit next to it, it show message on screen. If you want then I provided screen-sort.

Comment: What message did you see? The `Hello nasty World` or `We can't remove the item!` or something else? Please also provide the screenshot.

Comment: I see our custom message "THIS IS CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53162/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-rendy-eko-prastiyo).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I search some more things on this and finaly found my solution,

I need to just change the observer code like this.

```
app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\RemovecartbeforeObserver.php

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RemovecartbeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
   protected $messageManager;
   protected $_responseFactory;
   protected $_url;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url)
   {
       $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
       $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
       $this->_url = $url;
   }

   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
       // HERE IS MY CODE
       $message = "THIS IS CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE";
       $this->messageManager->addError($message);
       $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
       $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();            
       exit;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not working at my end don't know why :)

Comment: perfect answer!!! made my day. +1 :)

Comment: Error message not showing if cart is empty..

Comment: @jafarpinjar what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya,sorry its working for me

Answer (score 4):

Update your class to be like this:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;

class RemovecartbeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $redirectFactory;

    public function __construct(
        MessageManagerInterface $messageManager,
        RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $observer->getRequest()->setParam('item', false);

        $message = "THIS IS CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE";
        $this->messageManager->addError($message);

        return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: It show message on screen, but still it remove item from the cart. The goal is if observer generate the error then it not remove item from cart and show our custom message on screen.

Comment: `sales_quote_remove_item` is fired after you remove an item. If you want to do a check just before remove an item, you have to observe `sales_quote_item_delete_before`, not `sales_quote_remove_item`. Update `<event name="sales_quote_remove_item">` of your xml to `<event name="sales_quote_item_delete_before">`

Comment: still same output. It show message, but remove item from cart.

Comment: Have you cleaned & flushed the cache `bin/magento cache:clean && bin/magento cache:flush` after updating your xml?

Comment: yes, I run command

Comment: I have updated the answer. If it does not work, you have to find the way to set the `deleted` flag of `item` to false. Only if above code does not work, try to add `$observer->getEvent()->getItem()->setDeleted(false);` just before `return`. I don't know what is the item object sent by the event. If above code throws error, try `$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->setDeleted(false);`.

Comment: "Call to a member function setParam() on null " error when try first option.

Comment: "Call to a member function setDeleted() on null " when try 2 option.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. You may change `setDeleted(false)` to `isDeleted(false)`.

Comment: it show error like "Call to a member function isDeleted() on null in". I think I must used plugin method of magento to do this thing.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have told you before about the item object sent by the event. If `getItem()` is null, try `getQuoteItem()`. If it also fails, try dumping `$observer->getEvent()` to find the item object name.

Answer (score 0):

please follow if above solution is not workable:

[stop-product-add-t-cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/magento2-how-to-stop-a-product-from-getting-added-to-cart-programmatically)

Don't forget to upvote if you right diverted.

Answer (score 0):

check below code

```
class AttributeSaveBefore implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        
  throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__("custom error message."));
       
    }
}
```

some times redirectFactory not work so use simple to add exceptions.