# How to set Success message with specific location

Tags: magento2, checkout, controllers, session, messages

I have a custom module, with a controller that apply  discounts codes in payment page.

After the discount it's applied, I set a success message.
Now this message it's showing on homepage, even I apply the discount on payment page.
So to see the message I need to go on homepage.
My controller where I set the message look like this:

```
if($values){
        $this->chdxeckoutSession->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)
            ->collectTotals()
            ->save();
         $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                                __(
                                    'You used coupon code "%1".',
                                    $escaper->escapeHtml($couponCode)
                                )
                            );
```

Does anyone know how can I set the location for this message to be in *checkout/payment* page?

Comment: after setting sucees message, you can redirect customer to specific page.

Comment: the customer shold be on the same page after the message apper

Comment: You need to do that things. Or simple you can reload same page so message display on same page.

Comment: you don't understand my question! i set a cusom discount on payment page, and my message apper on homepage. I need this message on payment page

Comment: you need to check this, it may help you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158378/magento-2-event-observer-exception-not-showing-in-screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem that you try to make an Ajax request to the custom controller in the Checkout Page. Your custom controller should return JSON format.

```
        $response = [
            'errors' => false,
            'message' => 'The coupon code was applied.'
        ];

    $resultJson = $this->_resultJson->create();
    return $resultJson->setData($response);
```

In your Js function, you need to get the response message and show it. We can follow the Coupon form on the checkout page.