# how to get html code in config values magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, system.xml, core-config-data

I have created a field in admin configuration .I want to use the value of the field.If the value of the field is `<b>test</b>` it displays `<b>test</b>` not as **test**.how can I get it ?

Comment: how do you display it?

Comment: want to dispaly as **test**

Comment: like display test as bold right.

Comment: What your field type?

Comment: field type is text

Comment: what is the code you use to display it in frontend?

Comment: I think she is trying to add new page or block from admin but she didn't select the Editor mode right there that's why it is showing the attributes as well

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

[image]

I have to get the OTP message value in the helper code.I have created a helper function in Data.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 DeviMage. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Mage2Plugins\Sms\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class Data
 */
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    const XML_PATH_OTP_MESSAGE = 'mage2sms/settings/otp_message';

    /** @var logger  */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Get Otp Message
     *
     * @param string $storeId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOtpMessage($storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_OTP_MESSAGE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
    }


}
```

Get config value in observer check code below.

```
   <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 DeviMage. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Mage2Plugins\Sms\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Mage2Plugins\Sms\Helper\Data;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
/**
 * Class ContactMessagePost
 */
class ContactMessagePost implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var Data */
    protected $helper;

     /** @var Data */
    protected $logger;

    /** @var ManagerInterface */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * ContactMessagePost constructor.
     * @param Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $helper,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $message = $this->helper->getOtpMessage();
        //error message
        $this->messageManager->addError($message);

        //logger
        $this->logger->info("message =>".$message."<=");

    }

}
```

Then I have called one single line in the phtml file.

```
$required_loc = $this->helper('Mage2Plugins\Sms\Helper\Data')->getOtpMessage();
echo $required_loc;
```

Output as like **test**
[image]

Comment: I have to display config value in observer file

Comment: check I have update my answer

Comment: I have to display field value in
 throw new LocalizedException(__($fielsvalue));

Comment: the best way to  addError  in the observer. check I have update my observer code

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158378/magento-2-event-observer-exception-not-showing-in-screen

Comment: i want to get the field value in throw

Comment: Exception Not Showing in Screen when using throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($message));

Comment: best way to use try {
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($message);
        }