# Override Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct getAddToCartUrl() function

Tags: magento2, overrides, addtocart

In Magento 2

I want to override `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct`

I just want to pass my custom add to cart url before passing it to magento.

this function `getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = [])`

So far I've done in **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\AbstractProduct" />
</config>
```

And in `app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Product\AbstractProduct.php` I've following content.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

class AbstractProduct extends Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = [])
    {
       echo 'test';
       exit;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions if I want to process something before product is been added to magento cart.

Comment: follow http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/magento2-how-to-stop-a-product-from-getting-added-to-cart-programmatically

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with [Plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html):

*app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
        <plugin name="customParams"
                type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\Block\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

*app/code/Company/Module/Model/Plugin/Block/Product.php*

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model\Plugin\Block;

class Product
{
    public function beforeGetAddToCartUrl(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        $product, $additional = []
    )
    {
        //Your custom code here, can edit $additional param

        return [$product,  $additional];
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay let me try...

Comment: @KaushalSuthar are you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't override classes having "Abstract" keyword in Magento. Alternatively, you can override the class \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View as it is the child class of \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct, it should possesses all the property's and functions of it's base class.