# How can i give condition Shopping Cart Price Rules like if selected attribute products present in the cart, no other products allowed to add cart

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

If the customer selects my custom attribute products like "XYZ" to cart, after the customer not able to add other products to cart, the message showed "XYZ" attribute products present in the cart. and also other attributes products present in the cart, not able to add my "XYZ" attributes products to cart.

How can I do it by using Shopping Cart Price Rules?

Is any other options exits, let me know.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara : my question regard magento1

Comment: I just removed. dont mind. check and comment at existed answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using Shopping cart Price Rule Like if Product is added into cart then Restrict user to add more products into cart.

For this, you need to develop custom functionlity that will be implemented on before add to cart event and check if product is added into cart or not.

**For Reference:**

[Magento2 - How to stop a product from getting added to cart programmatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/magento2-how-to-stop-a-product-from-getting-added-to-cart-programmatically)

Comment: make sure my question is relevant to this one ::::  Magento2 - How to stop a product from getting added to cart programmatically?

Comment: i need :::::: If the customer selects my custom attribute products like "XYZ" to cart, after the customer not able to add other products to cart.

Comment: yes this event will work for your requirement