# Magento 2: Cart Page admin Settings

Tags: magento2, checkout

I would like to ask if there is a setting in the admin to limit customers quantity order.

Example. product limit per user is 4.

First transaction is 4 ordered products. Next transaction should not allow me to checkout because I already reached my quantity limit.

Is there a setting like that or should I create a module? Because if there is a default setting and I create a module, that module would be a waste.

Thanks. I hope someone answers.

Comment: Also. When I order the same product. The First order in cart disappears and the last order is only displaying. Is there any way to display both or if I ordered 1 on the first order and ordered 2 on the second one. qty in cart should be 3. Not override the 1 in to 2

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2 backend, you can set **Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** in

> Catalog > Product > Add/Edit > Advanced Inventory

[image]

You can globally change this setting as well here for all products in Configuration.

[image]

But once user place order with Max. Qty then after user can again add same number of QTY and they can place order again. So you just need to check how you can restrict that thing with your custom extension.

You can follow [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/magento2-how-to-stop-a-product-from-getting-added-to-cart-programmatically?answertab=oldest#tab-top) as a reference if you want to add any restriction.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I can still order with this setting. Is there any other way that if I can limit user with a specific qty? like if the user reached the max limit she/he cannot order again?

Comment: Yes, you can create your custom code for that. Default Magento is not provide this feature.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: You can follow this answer. You can do your changes easily with this.. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/magento2-how-to-stop-a-product-from-getting-added-to-cart-programmatically?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Let me know still if you need any help then. :)

Comment: How about ordering the same product in 2 transactions. But the first order disappeared and the cart only shows the 2nd order. The qty did not changed and followed the 2nd order transaction

Comment: I think you want to hide some orders on order history page ?

Comment: I'm not clear here. Can you please elaborate more here ?

Comment: This one also helpful to you to add restrictions.. https://webkul.com/blog/restrict-add-cart-according-condition-magneto2/

Comment: The scenario is this. I added 1 qty of a product in the car. Then I went to add another 2 of the same product. The cart only shows the last order of 2 qty. It is not adding up to 3.

Comment: Ill send you a SC

Comment: I sent a SC on our discussion yesterday