# Is there any way in magento 2 to prevent user to add more than 1 product in cart

Tags: magento2, cart, customer, addtocart, quantity

I want to set a limit of 1 product in the cart.
Magento 2 C.E provides an option to set a limit of qty of a single product in the cart but that option allows two individual products in the cart.
I want to set vice versa.
Users can add only one product at a time in the cart. user cannot add any other product if he added a product in the cart unless and until he removes the first product or checkout that product.
I am sure there will be a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Magento2 - How to stop a product from getting added to cart programmatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/magento2-how-to-stop-a-product-from-getting-added-to-cart-programmatically)

Let me know if this answer Is helpful....! Thanks

Comment: Yes as i mentioned in my question magento can restrict qty of one product but that configuration settings allows two individual product in cart. I want to restrict two individual products in cart.(simple products)

Comment: Oh so the overall product qty in the cart can't be more than 1?

Comment: Yes ,is there any way to restrict limit items in cart

Comment: Nope OOTB, but you can write a plugin/observer on add to cart method and prevent adding if there is already a item in your cart :)

Comment: Yes thats what im asking is there any way to do this whether by changing in code,custom module or any other way?

Comment: Take a look on this example, and add the logic you need https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/magento2-how-to-stop-a-product-from-getting-added-to-cart-programmatically

Comment: I have tried this code but didnot worked for me can u plz suggest me any thing  else

Comment: What did not work? 
The plugin didn't trigger?

Comment: You need to change the if statement to your needs :p 
if(this->quote->getItemsCount() == 1){ 
throw .... 
}

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. here i have just added a plugin and it works for me will it create problem if i have not added obseerver??

Comment: Nope, it won't.

Comment: Ok no problem .