# Magento2 Addtocart before plugin not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer, plugin, magento2.4.2

I have created before plugin for Add to cart functionality to check if product's custom attribute called My Tshirt(which is text field type) value "Jack"  or "Jill".

Plugin work properly but in plugin code product is not loading the custom attributes.  it;s loading product's default attributes.  I tried to load the custom attribute using **productRepository** but unfortunately it's not working. I want return error message on the frontend if Attribute value is "Jill".   in plugin code you can see "$product->getMyTshirt()"  is not working also, if I try $product->getData('my_tshirt')  that's also not working.  How can I load the custom attribute value in there.

```
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
   <plugin name="interceptAddingProductToCart"
        type="Jackson\Wyss\Model\Checkout\Cart\Plugin"
        sortOrder="10"
        disabled="false"/>
  </type>




 <?php
  namespace Jackson\Wyss\Plugin\Model\Checkout\Cart;
 use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
 class Plugin
{
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
 */
protected $productRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{

    try {           

        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productInfo->getId());
        if($product->getMyTshirt() == 'Jill'){

           throw new LocalizedException(__('Could not add Product to Cart'));
       }
        
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()));
    
    }

    return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];



 }
 }
```

I tried to use observer **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add** as well. If I use that observer and add to cart on the frontend, it's simply reloading the page and in observer not getting product data as well.  I followed below article but still no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

[Magento2 - How to stop a product from getting added to cart programmatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/magento2-how-to-stop-a-product-from-getting-added-to-cart-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your attribute like this. No need to load repository, you already have the product model with $productInfo

```
public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
{
    try {

      $attr = $productInfo->getResource()->getAttribute('my_tshirt');
      $myTshirt = (string)$attr->getFrontend()->getValue($productInfo);

      if ($myTshirt == 'Jack' || $myTshirt == 'Jill') {
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Could not add Product to Cart'));
      }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  it works!

Answer (score -1):

1)Create di.xml in app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="interceptAddingProductToCart"
                type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Checkout\Cart\Plugin"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="interceptAddingProductToCart"
                type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Checkout\Cart\Plugin"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2)Create Plugin.php in app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Model/Checkout/Cart and add the following code:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Checkout\Cart;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Plugin
{
    
    public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
 
        try {
    
            // Your custom code here.
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
 
        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that.That's not working.

Comment: kindly upvote my answer

Comment: Help me to find the solution please.